# get_header(), get_footer() from plugin template

Tags: templates, page-template

I have created a plugin that registers a custom post type. I would like to load a custom header and footer for the custom post type from the plugin.

After some google research I can see that it's not possible to use get_header() to load and so I have tried using:

```
<?php get_template_part('header', 'trademanager'); ?>
```

Which I can now see is exactly the same as using get_header() and so it obviously fails. The codex has pointed me towards load_template()
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_template

I don't really understand how to use it, can someone help me figure this out please?

My custom theme file is header-trademanager.php and is located in plugin/templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but maybe my answer will help someone.

---

Short answer is:

use `load_template()` function with full file server path as first argument passed to it.

---

Long answer:

`get_header()` using the function `locate_template()` which uses the function `load_template()` which uses the function `require_once()`. Thus, to load the header layout from a plugin or any other directory, you can directly use `require_once()` and this will be completely correct if global variables like `$post` and `$wp_query` are **not** needed, otherwise case, use the `load_template()` function passing the full server path to the file as the first argument.

---

P.S.

For more certainty, you can look at the files `wp-includes/general-template.php` and `wp-includes/template.php`, which contain all these functions. And you will see that there is no complicated logic in them, everything is very simple.
The only reason it’s better to use standard features is support. Support for the development of WP code lies on the shoulders of the team of developers, and your own functions are on yours.

But in this case, when you need to require your own `header` file - this may be a justifiable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can change the loaded file for get_header/get_footer to something outside the stylesheet/theme directory.

If you put header-trademanager.php in the theme folder, `get_header("trademanager")` should work.

I had expected to see a filter applied somewhere in get_header or locate_template, but it seems that it's not customizable at this point.

Comment: I can't place the file in a theme folder, it must be in the plugin folder. Do you know anything about load_template()?

Comment: I don't believe load_template is what you want. It'll allow you to use another template file entirely, but not to just override the header that's loaded. What exactly is the difference between your header and the default header? Maybe it can be achieved in a different manner.

Comment: The plugin kind of acts as a backend display for the custom post type so I dont want the themes header to load but I dont want to have to code the head section on every page.

Comment: But you're using a custom template already, why use get_header() at all instead of simply requiring your header-trademanager.php and executing wp_head() in there?

Comment: Im using load_template() and its working nicely so far. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no filter that can be used to change the location of the header template. You can change the name of the template, but it has to be in the theme or child theme directory. This is unlike all the other theme templates that can be filtered, header and footer templates have to be in theme or child theme folders.

Function load_template() doesn't have filters to change the file path.

Answer (score 0):

In general front end should not be handled in a plugin except for widgets and shortcodes. Front end is the sole responsibility of a theme.

You can play with this or that hook and get something that works somtimes, but it is unlikely to work with all themes.

Best bet is to utilize the `page.php` or `single.php` templates of the theme. Load it for your post type, and manipulate whatever is possible there. Still this is at best just to be able to have some output, the chances of it to actually look good for more than the few themes you will test it with are slim.

Answer (score 0):

Because the standard get_header and get_footer won't work inside a plugin, you could consider simply replacing get_header() and get_footer with PHP's include statement, for instance:

```
include 'header-trademanager.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('get_header', 'replace_header');

function replace_header(){
    require PLUGIN_DIR.'includes/templates/header.php';

    $templates   = [];
    $templates[] = 'header.php';
    remove_all_actions( 'wp_head' );
    ob_start();
    locate_template( $templates, true );
    ob_get_clean();
}
```